# Trying to select and count all the matching terms in my wp_post and wp_term_relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to make a query that looks sort of like this:

#### what I'm  trying to accomplish

getting a count of each term_taxonomy_id that corresponds to a
`wp_post.ID` and `wp_term_relationship`. So, I can display a count for each where the desired count value corresponds to that respective `wp_term_relationship.term_taxonomy_id`.
So, I wrote the following test query and didn't have any luck:

```
$db_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_post.ID, wp_term_relationship.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationship.object_id");
```

I know this wouldn't receive the count but am I at all on the right track here. If you need anymore information let me know and I will update according.

### Sample data

`wp_posts table`-> ID, post_author, etc.. I'm only concerned about the ID attribute from the posts table
`wp_term_relationship`-> object_id, term_taxonomy_id im only really concerned about term_taxonomy_id here.

Comment: Can you please share the tables structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

you have enter wrong table name "wp_term_relationship" its "wp_term_relationships".
run below query .

```
$db_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id");
```

tell me if there is any problem